# C# for loop comparing next value with current value

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, for-loop

i have this piece of code here , basically i am doing a for loop as i retrieve records from database( using entity framework ) but when i want to compare using if statement theres an error :

```
       IList<Model.question> lstQuestion = qn.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);

        for(int i = 0 ; i <lstQuestion.Count()-1 ; i++)
        {
             .... //code here

            if(lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo == lstQuestion[i++].QuestionNo) // error at i++
            {
                tb.Text = lstQuestion[i++].QuestionContent;
                sp1.Children.Add(tb);
            }
```

i tried

> lstQuestion.Count() instead of lstQuestion.Count()-1;

also doesn't work .

QuestionNo is a column in my database table .

Full ERROR :

[image]

When i remove the whole if statement , it works fine .

Comment: InnerException says {"Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget."}

Answer (score 0):

you're incrementing `i` three times. Try this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <lstQuestion.Count(); i++)
        {
             .... //code here

            if(lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo == 1stQuestion[i+1].QuestionNo) // error at i++
            {
                tb.Text = lstQuestion[i+1].QuestionContent;
                sp1.Children.Add(tb);
            }
```

Comment: it sounds like it's the line `sp1.Children.Add(tb);` that's causing you trouble. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do there without seeing it in context. `tb` is apparently already a child of something else.

Comment: i didn't paste the full code because i tot it was not related , sp1 is the name of the stackpanel that i am adding the tb to.

Comment: i removed sp1.children.add(tb) and tb.text line but i keep the if statement , the error is still

Comment: @user2376998 Your loop is incorrect. See my answer for the correct loop. But i agree with Bodacious that sp1.Children.Add(tb); is causing you trouble as well.

Comment: @EhsanUllah yeah, I thought about that as well after I answered, but It seems like he's still having the problem even with `count()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a number 1 in the == 1stQuestion[i] instead of the lowercase L like in the ohter lstQuestion[i] references.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem with if statement.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i <lstQuestion.Count()-1; i++)
    {
         .... //code here

        if(lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo == 1stQuestion[i+1].QuestionNo) 
        {
            tb.Text = lstQuestion[i+1].QuestionContent;
            sp1.Children.Add(tb);
        }
```

But i think you are getting error on this line

```
                      sp1.Children.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ++i instead of i++.

```
IList<Model.question> lstQuestion = qn.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);

        for(int i = 0 ; i <lstQuestion.Count()-1 ; i++)
        {
             .... //code here

            if(lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo == lstQuestion[++i].QuestionNo) // error at i++
            {
                tb.Text = lstQuestion[i].QuestionContent;
                sp1.Children.Add(tb);
            }
```